# What is the role of time (time interval) in principle of least action?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, time, variational-principle, action

Action is represented by $S[Q(t)]$ where $Q(t)$ is the name of a single complete path in the configuration space of a system. The path starts at the point $q_i$ and ends at the point $q_f$. Suppose that the system is at $q_i$ at the time $t=0$ and then suppose it reaches $q_f$ at $t=T$. Then the action functional for this whole path $Q(t)$is calculated as:
$$S[Q(t)]=\int_{0}^{T} L(q,\dot{q},t)dt=A  [ML^2T^{-1}].$$ Here $L$ is the Lagrangian. Now please suppose that I applied the principle of least action and incidentally found out that $A$ is the least possible action of all the possible paths those take same time $T$.

Now suppose that I found another path $Q'(t)$between same end points $q_i$ to $q_f$ but the system takes time $T'$ instead of $T$ to reach at $q_f$ from $q_i$. For this path $$S[Q'(t)]=\int_{0}^{T'} L(q,\dot{q},t)dt=A'[ML^2T^{-1}].$$

Now if $A'\le A$ then what will be the actual path of the system? $Q(t)$ or $Q'(t)$?

So, my question is what is the role of time interval in the principle of least action?

Or should the time taken for each possible paths from $q_i$ to $q_f$ be always same or they can be different?

Comment: Are you assuming $Q'$ is also a stationary point of the action?

Comment: $Q'$ is the name of just another path. I am not assuming anything about $Q'$. I am just asking whether $Q'$ will represent the stationary point of action or $Q$ will represent the stationary point of action. (Please see in the question that $Q$ and $Q'$ take different time interval)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brief answer: The integration region $[t_i,t_f]$ is kept fixed in the [principle of least/extremal/stationary action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action)/[Hamilton's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%27s_principle). To allow variation of the integration region $[t_i,t_f]$, one should use other [variational principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_principle), such as e.g. [Maupertuis' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maupertuis%27s_principle)/principle of abbreviated action.